# Capture a photo by Intent

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make the "Take photo" tutorial from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) and after following all the steps I still have an error. More exactly after I take the picture it displays the message "camera has stopped". I added a button that opens the camera on click and an imageView to display the photo. I am trying to deploy the app on Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android 8.0.0,API 26).

This is the setOnClickListener:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById((R.id.button));
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            button.setEnabled(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();

            }
        });
    }
```

And this is the methos for camera:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File imageView = null;
            try {
                imageView = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (imageView != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.camapp.fileprovider",
                        imageView);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
```

The file path:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path
            name="my_images"
            path="Android/data/com.example.camapp/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

And the permission:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Provider:

```
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.camapp.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
```

And i have the same method for onActivityResult() createImageFile() and galleryAddPic() from the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics).

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/model/AndroidModuleModel.getRootDir must not return null
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.$$$reportNull$$$0(AndroidModuleModel.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.getRootDir(AndroidModuleModel.java:571)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.android.ContentRootsModuleSetupStep.findContentEntries(ContentRootsModuleSetupStep.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.android.ContentRootsModuleSetupStep.doSetUpModule(ContentRootsModuleSetupStep.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.android.ContentRootsModuleSetupStep.doSetUpModule(ContentRootsModuleSetupStep.java:41)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.ModuleSetupStep.setUpModule(ModuleSetupStep.java:35)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.common.BaseSetup.setUpModule(BaseSetup.java:41)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.ModuleSetup.setupModuleModels(ModuleSetup.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.CachedProjectModelsSetup.setUpModules(CachedProjectModelsSetup.java:116)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.ProjectSetup$ProjectSetupImpl.setUpProject(ProjectSetup.java:82)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncResultHandler.onSyncSkipped(SyncResultHandler.java:164)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.trySyncWithCachedGradleModels(NewGradleSync.java:219)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.sync(NewGradleSync.java:165)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.access$000(NewGradleSync.java:59)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync$2.run(NewGradleSync.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I want to make a button that opens the camera take a picture and save it in the gallery or other specified directory because I will make some image processing on that photo.I tried almost all the tutorials on yt and I really had a hard time finding a solution for this problem.I appreciate any solution or suggestion you have.Thank you for you're time!

Comment: Have you added camera permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> `
 along storage permission in your manifest file ?

Comment: As @RakhiDhavale suggested, you might need more permission, otherwise I think that you should move your call to galleryAddPic() at the end of  OnActivityResult() to make sure that your file exists and contains your picture.

Comment: Please post stacktrace

Comment: @JohnJoe I added the stacktrace. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

If your app requires the camera to click a picture, the CAMERA permission should be asked

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<!-- other permissions go here -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application ...>
    ...
</application>
```

Your app should then prompt user to grant the camera & storage permissions

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivityName.this,
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            YOUR_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);

    // YOUR_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.

} else {
// Permission has already been granted
}
```

Also define the file provider in manifest file

```
 <provider
 android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
 android:authorities="com.yourPackageName.fileprovider"
 android:exported="false"
 android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/file_list"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

Comment: Ok, I added "android.permission.CAMERA" permission in AndroidManifest and now after I click the button it displays the message "camera has stopped" without launching the camera. I also added the galleryAddPic() at the end of OnActivityResult().It is any chance to be an error from activity_main.xml ?

Comment: Are you asking the user to grant camera & storage permission , before taking picture , on button click ? Refer this link on requesting permissions https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: If you're a newbie and have issues in implementation refer this tutorial link http://www.zoftino.com/android-capture-image-from-camera-and-save

Comment: Thanks for tutorial! I will try to make the steps from there again.

Comment: Now i have permissions but now i have the same problem from beginning. After I take the picture it displays the message "camera has stopped"